# how to track user activity in windows using php?

Tags: php, windows

So we plan to track a user's activity within client site(in windows).
What we want to know track :
get list of running applications.
get current open application name.
get how many time spending on which application ?
is it possible in php ?

Comment: I really recommend you to use PowerShell for those tasks. What you want can be written in ~3 lines of code in PowerShell. Much easier than doing such things with PHP.

Comment: Php is the wrong language for this.

Comment: Specifically, it's the wrong language because the idea behind PHP is that it runs on the *server*, and not on the client.

Comment: It is **impossible** to track, how much time a user spends on any given application, irrespective of the programming language or framework used. You can monitor, how long any given window is in the foreground, but that's a pretty weak indication of actual user activity. You can also monitor input, but if you monitor lack of input, this doesn't necessitate user inactivity either. It sounds like you need to go back to the drawing board, and properly deduce your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be possible in PHP, but if you want to stick with a web-based language such as PHP, the PHP server would have to be running on the machine you want to track, or PHP would only be the backend-processing half that accepts data from a client application.

If you're okay with tracking activity on a PHP server, try looking at the [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function to execute external programs. Be aware that any executables called must be compatible with the operating system you're using and installed on the machine.

I would advise you not to use PHP to track user activity, but rather a language that's more suited to writing client applications and interfacing with the operating system APIs.